# I'm using OrangeHRM 5.5. On building web client app with NPM facing error

Tags: vue.js

Here's the error snippet

```
ERROR in src/core/util/services/api.service.ts:163:9
TS2345: Argument of type '(config: AxiosRequestConfig) => AxiosRequestConfig<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>) => InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any> | Promise<InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>>'.
  Type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>' is not assignable to type 'InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any> | Promise<InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>>'.
    Type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>' is not assignable to type 'InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>'.
      Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
        Type 'AxiosHeaders | (Partial<RawAxiosHeaders & { Accept: AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Length": AxiosHeaderValue; "User-Agent": AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Encoding": AxiosHeaderValue; Authorization: AxiosHeaderValue; } & { ...; }> & Partial<...>) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<RawAxiosHeaders & { Accept: AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Length": AxiosHeaderValue; "User-Agent": AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Encoding": AxiosHeaderValue; Authorization: AxiosHeaderValue; } & { ...; }>'.
    161 |       // Additional interceptors for caching
    162 |       this._http.interceptors.request.use(
  > 163 |         (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
        |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    164 |           if (config.url) {
    165 |             const url = config.url;
    166 |             const cachedEtag = this._cacheStorage.getItem(url);
```

Downloaded version from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/orangehrm) working fine as it's downloaded with a build. When I try to build from the source code, it's throwing above errors.

I did check on forum but it's outdated. Any help will be appreciated.